# Add dll files to maven build

Tags: java, maven, dll

I have two `dll` files: Assembler.Dll and Cpp.dll. They are currently under /src/main/resources. While i'm building maven project by calling: `maven clean package assembly:single` I'm getting .jar file, which after invoking getting me an error: `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no Cpp in java.library.path`.

How can I pack my `dll` files together with other dependencies in maven? I want this jar to be executable on every computer with Windows, without putting in java.path my dll files.

Plugin config:

```
   <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>sample.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: This is not technically possibly. There are workarounds which involve quite a bit of work on your end. You can JAR the .DLL files into your Uber JAR, then extract them into the current directory before your application performs a loadLibrary on them. This will require the current working directory be in your java.library.path. .DLL's are native binaries and the JVM does not know how to load native binaries from the classpath.

Comment: @AndrewTFinnell I can't guarantee that the user which will use my application will run my JAR at java.library.path directory